# How to specify the ip and port of the Selenium server in the RemoteDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

If I understand it correctly, we can have a server machine running Selenium+Chrome+Chrome driver,
and a client machine that uses the RemoteWebDriver:

On the server we execute this:

```
$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-{VERSION}.jar
```

On the client, we have a Java program with something like:

```
WebDriver driver = RemoteWebDriver.builder()
     .addAlternative(new ChromeOptions())
     .setCapabilitiy("proxy", new Proxy())
     .build();
driver.get("http://example.com/");
```

However, how does the client know the ip and port of the server?

Ref:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/remote.html
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [URL](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriverBuilder.html#url-java.net.URL-) on the RemoteWebDriver to your server.

```
WebDriver driver = RemoteWebDriver.builder().url(new URL("https://here.com:1234")).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is the Selenium Server's ones, you can get help in below page:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/configuration/toml_options/#standalone
You can set port number and other parameters with a TOML file.
You make a toml file like 'config.toml' and fill it like below:

```
[server]
port = 4445
host = "localhost"
```

and run

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-{VERSION}.jar --config (toml_file_path.toml)
```

In client, you can specify the URI of the Remote WebDriver Server like

```
http://(server ip):(port number)
```